# Exponential generating function of binomial coefficients in pascal's triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Does there exist any closed form formula for the following exponential generating function:

$$
F_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{2(k+n)-1}{n}x^n}{(k+n)!}
$$

The coefficients in the numerator are vertical binomial coefficients in pascal's triangle.

[image]

For example, in the image, for $k=2$ we have,

$$F_2(x) = \frac{1x^0}{2!}+\frac{5x^1}{3!}+\frac{21x^2}{4!}+\frac{84x^3}{5!}+...$$

Comment: Mathematica and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B2+%28k+%2B+n%29+-+1%2C+n%5D+x%5En%2F%28k+%2B+n%29%21+%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D) give the result $$F_2(k)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{2 (k+n)-1}{n}}{(k+n)!}\, x^n=\frac{\, _2F_2\left(k,k+\frac{1}{2};2 k,k+1;4 x\right)}{k!}=\Gamma(2 k)\, _2\tilde{F}_2\left(k,k+\frac{1}{2};2 k,k+1;4 x\right)$$ but I'm not sure you'd consider this a closed form.

Comment: The sequence is on https://oeis.org/A002054 and they give formulas, generating functions...